# Reading XML with PHP, including DTD entities?

Tags: php, xml, dtd

I am trying to read a 40MB large XML with PHP's XMLReader but I cannot get the contents of fields such as:

```
<pos>&n;</pos>
<misc>&abbr;</misc>
```

they have definitions in the file such as:

```
<!ENTITY abbr "abbreviation">
<!ENTITY n "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)">
```

but how to I get them to be displayed?

thanks!

Comment: You want the `&n;` to be translated into `abbreviation` for output?

Comment: This should help with that: http://php.net/manual/en/example.xml-external-entity.php

Comment: @Marc: "You want the &n; to be translated into abbreviation for output?" I want the &abbr; to be translated into "abbreviation" using, if possible the functions from the XMLReader class at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

If I switch now to another method to parse XML, I will have to rewrite tons of code...

Comment: Try the `XMLReader::SUBST_ENTITIES ` option as documented on that page.

Comment: THANKS! That was the solution! I have been overlooking this the whole time! :-) You want to put that into the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `XMLReader::SUBST_ENTITIES` option as documented on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/example.xml-external-entity.php).